# Line Thickness Detection using image processing techniques

Tags: python, image, preprocessor, linegraph

I have a line graph image. I want to find the thickness of the line in the graph. What are possible options to find the thickness of the line in graph image?

solutions I thought of:
1)I thought of setting the width of the line on my own. But I am not sure how to do that.2) Another solution can be through finding the contours of the line and then finding the area of the contours for the thickness of the line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide more details such as code and explain the problem clearly with an image.